# Module-wide variables python

Tags: python, tkinter, module, sqlite

I am trying to import a value from my module called **SignIn** and use it in a main module to apply a sqlite query to it. The variable is called username and is assigned when the user enters it in a tkinter window. I also have a database **passwordDbase** in the python file Password_database that has all of the usernames in it. How do I import this value into another module without circular dependency/cycle importing ('as i keep getting SignIn is not callable'). Thanks in advance. 
SignIn looks like:

```
import tkinter
def login():
    global username
    username=entry_user.get()
win=tkinter.Tk()
entry_user=tkinter.Entry(win)
#with a bunch of other tkinter functions to make textboxes etc
```

My main programme looks like:

```
import sqlite3
import SignIn
import Password_database
SignIn()
Password_database()
conn = sqlite3.connect ('passwordDbase.db')
c = conn.cursor()
username=SignIn.username
username=username.strip()
c.execute('''SELECT * FROM passwordDbase WHERE employee_username=?''',(username,))
rows = c.fetchall()
row = c.fetchone()

rows=c.fetchall()
if len(rows) != 1:
   message=' '
else:
   message= 'correct'

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: If Python says it's not callable, then it's not callable. Don't try to call it. (line 4, `SignIn()`)

Comment: What does "SignIn()" do?

Comment: Looks like that you want to call `SignIn.login()`.

Comment: Why are you attempting to call the `SignIn` and `Password_database` modules? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: when you import `SignIn` then it automatically executes code which is not inside functions so you don't have to (and you can't) execute `SignIn()`.

Comment: maybe you should run functions with arguments instead of global variables. Or simply put all in one file and create normal program, and later you will split code in many files - after you learn how to use tkinter, functions and classes.

Comment: as for me you should keep code in functions and then you have better control when it will be executed and you can run it with arguments. And I would import code with SQL into code with Tkinter, not code with Tkinter into code with SQL - so I would build GUI on top of SQL (GUI wrapper for SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't resolve your problem but I would organize all in different way.

Inside `mydatabase.py` I would keep functions which work with database

```
import sqlite3

def get_user(username):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('passwordDbase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM passwordDbase WHERE employee_username=?', (username,))
    conn.commit()

    rows = c.fetchall()

    if len(rows) != 1:
        message = 'error'
        data = None
    else:
        message = 'correct'
        data = rows[0]

    c.close()
    conn.close()

    return message, data


def check_pasword(username, password):
    pass


def other_function_on_database():
    pass
```

And I would import this into code with `tkinter`

```
import tkinter as tk
import mydatabase

# --- functions ---

def login():
    username = entry_username.get()
    password = entry_password.get()

    username = username.strip()

    message, data = mydatabase.login(username)
    result_label['text'] = message

    #if data and data[x] == password:
    #    result_label['text'] = "correct"

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

entry_username = tk.Entry(win)
entry_username.pack()

entry_password = tk.Entry(win)
entry_password.pack()

button_login = tk.Button(win, text="Login", command=login)
button_login.pack()

result_label = tk.Label(win, text="")
result_label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

This way file with `tkinter` is main file and I build GUI wrapper for database functions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to prevent code execution at import, use

```
#mymodule.py
class MyModule(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

def MyFunc(myparam):
    print myparam

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this code gets executed when the module is called like
    # python mymodule.py
    print "MyModule called, not imported"
```

If you want it executed at import, place it inside the module-scope, not the "`if __name__ == "__main__":`" scope.

Second, if you want to import "static" values from a module define them inside the module like:

```
#mymodule.py
MyModuleText="Text"
MyModuleList=["My", "Module", "List"]

class MyModule(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

def MyFunc(myparam):
    print myparam

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this code gets executed when the module is called like
    # python mymodule.py
    print "MyModule called, not imported"
```

then use

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mymodule
print mymodule.MyModuleText
print mymodule.MyModuleList
```

this will access the variables from the module.

If you want to run functions from the module, call them.
To use classes, create instances.

```
#mymodule.py
MyModuleText="Text"
MyModuleList=["My", "Module", "List"]

class MyModule(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def some_method(self, text):
        print "MyModule.some_func %s"%text

def MyFunc(myparam):
    print myparam

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this code gets executed when the module is called like
    # python mymodule.py
    print "MyModule called, not imported"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mymodule

myinstance = mymodule.MyClass()
myinstance.some_method("SomeMethod from outside")

mymodule.MyFunc("MyModuleFunction called")
```